# get file path from url in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, facebook-php-sdk, filepath

I am using php sdk for uploading images to facebook album.For this I need to give real path of Images.Incase of my server I can give real path of the image and upload to facebook is working fine. But here I want to upload images to facebook album via using external image URL.
ie,I want to upload image to fb by using following image URL.http://i.nokia.com/r/image/view/-/2003984/highRes/2/-/Lumia-620-Smart-Shoot.jpg

```
$this->facebook->setFileUploadSupport(TRUE);

           $photo = $this->facebook->api('/*********/photos', 'POST', array(
                      'access_token' => $this->config->item('facebook_page_access_token'),
                      'source' => '@' .$imagePath,
                      'message' => "description text"
                          )
          );
```

This is my code for uploading images to FB.
here how can I get path of the image by using given URL in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can publish a photo from external source using the 'url' parameter.

```
    $photo = $this->facebook->api('/*********/photos', 'POST', array(
      'access_token' => $this->config->item('facebook_page_access_token'),
      'url' => $imagePath,
      'message' => "description text"
       )
);
```

checkout the below document.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/